# synchronization in java with multiple JVM instances in GAE environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My Problem is:
I want to persist an entity in GAE datastore if it's not already persisted.

**My code's Algorithm is:**

```
select * from Employee where code=1234;
 if record not found then:
    persist it;
 otherwise
    do nothing;
```

It's very easy to do, but it is being complex in multi threaded environment. Here the problem occurs when two threads are trying to execute above query at the same time. both gets `null` so both the threads are persisting entity. So instead of only one, Two records are getting created in data base
Here I have synchronized the complete method, but due to multiple instances of jvm in GAE env, it's not working.

Please suggest me the proper solution. 
My Technology Stack which I am using:
java, Spring, REST, GAE datastore.

Comment: are you using [tag:google-cloud-datastore] or [tag:google-cloud-sql] because you show psuedo SQL and the [tag:google-cloud-datastore] does not support that. It is unclear what you are asking because you spammed the tags with unrelated tags. Please clarify.

Comment: I am using google-cloud-datastore, Psuedo Sql is just for explaining my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can workaround this with two different Kinds as below:

- Employee Kind - stores your normal data for employee entities

  - Key (Auto-assigned numeric)
  - Employee Number (Code)
  - Name, etc.
- EmployeeNumberConstraint Kind - This is strictly for enforcing uniqueness on employee number

  - Key (same as employee number from Employee Entity)

For inserting a new employee -

- Begin a Transaction
- Insert an entity of Kind `EmployeeNumberConstraint` with the key value set to the employee number (2.g. 1234)
- Insert an entity of Kind `Employee` (auto generated key and employee number = 1234)
- Commit the transaction

If you try to insert an employee entity with an existing employee number, the insert to `EmployeeNumberConstraint` fails with ALREADY_EXISTS exception. Roll back the transaction for any exceptions. Basically, uniqueness is guaranteed by the Datastore with the use of two Kinds and transaction. So, you don't need to do any synchronization in Application.

For deleting an employee - make sure to delete both entities - one from `Employee` Kind and the corresponding from `EmployeeNumberConstraint`, in the same transaction.